# Want SSRS parameter to automatically execute report when selected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Have an SSRS 2016 report which has a parameter that needs user selection before a report can be generated.  It is in the form of a drop down with no default value.  When a user selects a value from this drop down, the user will then need to click the view report button.  Is it possible to skip this step, i.e. when a user selects a value from the drop-down, have SSRS automatically generate the report?  Seems like having to click on the view report button is just an unnecessary step.

Comment: Yes, but not from the SSRS side. You can use JQuery to listen for a parameter change and then automatically hit the "view report" button after. [Example here](http://camerontownshend.blogspot.com/2012/11/ssrs-automatically-view-report-after.html).

Comment: I was hoping this could be done through SSRS since no additional web work will be done to the reports.  Oh well.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to hide the parameter bar altogether and have the parameter options populate a table in the report that you can click on to reload with that parameter selected.